# Search auto complete / suggestions usage

Tags: user-behavior, search, autocomplete

**Does anybody have any statistics as to how many people end up selecting an auto-suggestion versus typing their own search phrase when performing a search online with auto-suggestion capabilities?** (whether Google or a website internal search)

Obviously it might have to do with the quality of the auto-suggestions, and thus figures will differ whether we're talking about Google (assumption is that suggestions are pretty good) or a random website (assumption is that suggestions aren't as good), but I'd like to get an idea of how inclined to using auto-suggestions people usually are.

I could find existing questions on the net, but unfortunately no answers:
http://www.quora.com/Google/How-many-people-use-Google-Suggest

Comment: It's going to be tricky to answer because autosuggestions (particularly in google) become autocomplete the more letters you type. So if you're interested in 'FISHING' and you start typing `F-I-S-H-I-N` it's going to suggest `FISHING` anyway, so users might just click that instead of typing the last `G`. That way it's hard to quantify whether it's autosuggest that's working and suggesting something or whether it's just working as an autocomplete instead.

Comment: In my case I consider auto-complete and auto-suggestion to be the same: it's about users selecting something that's proposed to them instead of typing something of their own, thus reducing the variety of searches. I'm in charge of keyword analysis on a website but the 300K different monthly searches make it very difficult, as advanced text analytic is required to group searches by themes and highlight pain points/areas of interest. Introducing auto-suggestion will help us, but I'm wondering how much, hence the question.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently a research study done on the effectiveness of autocomplete and auto suggestions in a library website shows that people do use it. To [quote the research article](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://ejournals.bc.edu/ojs/index.php/ital/article/download/1930/pdf&ei=OwCeUv_-GMH4rQff_ICYDg&usg=AFQjCNFZHXfOho3TYz-J7tliVE3C1nw0LQ&sig2=9jexdeI7IwpMM5PurFExZw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bmk)

> The study’s findings were consistent across both rounds of usability
> testing. Notable themes include using autocomplete to correct spelling
> on known-item searches (specific titles, authors, etc.), to build
> student confidence with an unfamiliar topic, to speed up the search
> process, to focus broad searches, and to augment search-term
> vocabulary. The study also details important student perceptions about
> autocomplete that can guide the implementation process in both library
> systems and instructional scenarios. These student perceptions include
> themes of autocomplete’s popularity, desire for local resource
> suggestions, various cosmetic page changes, and user perception of the
> value of autocomplete to their peers.

The article also states that autocomplete had the maximum value in these factors

- **Checking the spelling** : As per the article, users often relied on autocomplete to check the spelling and to ensure they were on the right track. To quote the article

> Correcting search-term spelling is a key way in which students chose
> to make use of the autocomplete feature. For known-item searches, all
> eight students in the second round of testing selected suggestions
> from auto-complete at least two times out of the three searches
> conducted. Of those eight students, four (50 percent) used
> auto-complete every time (three out of three opportunities), and four
> (50 percent) used it 67 percent of the time (two out of three
> opportunities). We found that of this latter group who only selected
> auto-complete suggestions two out of the three opportunities
> presented, three of them did in fact refer to the dropdown selections
> when typing their inquiries, but did not actively select these
> suggestions from the dropdown all three times.
>
> In choosing to use
> autocomplete for spelling correction, one student noted that
> autocomplete was helpful “if you have an idea of a word but not how
> it’s spelled.

- **Locating known items** : The study also states that autocomplete was significant when users knew what they were searching for but had a partial recollection of the item. To quote the article

> Another significant use of the autocomplete feature was in cases where
> students were looking for a specific item but had only a partial
> citation. In one case, a student used autocomplete to find a specific
> course text by typing in the general topic (e.g., “Africa”) and then
> an author’s name that the course instructor had recommended. The
> Google implementation did an excellent job of combining these pieces
> of information into a list of actual book titles from which to choose.
> This finding also echoes those of White and Marchioni, who note that
> autocomplete “improved the quality of initial queries for both known
> item and exploratory tasks.

- **Speed** : As expected speed was another significant factor which was emphasized on by the users in the study. To quote the article

> The study also showed that speed is a factor in deciding when to use
> autocomplete functionality. Specifically, autocomplete should be
> implemented in a way in which they are not perceived as slowing down
> the search process. This includes having results displayed in a way
> that is easily ignored if students want to type in an entire search
> phrase themselves, and having the presentation and selection of search
> suggestions done in a way that is easy to read and quick to be
> selected. Autocomplete is perceived as a time-saver when clicking on
> an item will shorten the amount of typing students need to do.
> However, some students will ignore autocomplete altogether; they do
> this when they know what they want, and they feel that speed is
> compromised if they need to stop and look at the suggestions when they
> already know what they want to search. In the study, different
> participants would often cite speed as a reason for both selecting and
> not selecting an item for the same question, particularly with the
> known-item searches

- Confidence: Confidence that the topic existed was another reason for people using autocomplete

> ***“[Autocomplete is] an assurance that it [the research topic] is out there . . . you’re not the first person to look for it.”—student
> participant***
>
> There were multiple themes related to the concept of user confidence
> discovered in the study. First, some participants noted that when they
> see the suggestions provided by autocomplete it verifies that what
> they are searching is “real”—validating their research idea and giving
> them the sense that others have been successful previously searching
> for their topic

Hence though this is a case of a study done for a specific audience, it can very well be applied to other user bases where people are researching for content and are using the search to find it.